# Compiling with -m32 -mtune=native on AMD64

Tags: gcc, x86-64

Is it a correct assessment that compiling with -m32 and -mtune=native on a AMD64 machine will use 32 bits for pointers and hence slightly smaller data structures, and consequently a denser cache packing. My application (it is still in its design stage) will not need more than a GB of memory so a 32 bit address space should be fine. I am hoping to utilize the bit-shrunk data structures for more data in cache, and also the potential to use more registers for integer math. What I am trying to achieve is the best of both worlds, more registers by virtue of -mtune=native, but smaller pointers by -m32. Will the availability of extra registers be taken care of largely automatically or do I have to deal explicitly with sse. I would rather not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least if I understand what you want, I don't think the compiler is going to do the job for you. It'd going to produce either 32-bit or 64-bit code. With 64-bit code, the pointers will be 64 bits -- if you want 32-bit pointers, you're going to have to generate 32-bit code (with its commensurate limitations, such as on what registers it'll use).

To get what you want, I'm pretty sure you'll have to split the pointer up yourself: store a (probably 64-bit) base address, and inside your data structure, store offsets rather than complete addresses. You'll need to add the base and offset together yourself before you attempt to de-reference though.

Comment: Ah! I see. Nice solution, though its more work. Wish the compiler did it.

Comment: @san: Microsoft's compiler has what they call `__based` pointers, which are pretty much what I've described. I don't *think* gcc has a direct counterpart, but it might be worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, -m32 should use 32-bit pointers. You could confirm that by printing sizeof(int *).

However 64bit applications have more registers accessible in the instruction set (in addition to them being larger) - so you might get the opposite effect. It depends on the application which effect (larger pointers vs more registers) has a bigger impact, generally I would suggest trying both and comparing the performance.

Comment: I was hoping to get the benefit of having lots of registers by -mtune=native but without having large pointers (enforced by -m32). Basically try to have the best of both worlds. Yeah I will compare when I get done, but just wanted to get a sense if my expectation is even reasonable or not.

Comment: Even with -mtune=native the basic instruction set is still x86 with its limited number of registers. It is possible that you profit from SSE (which has additional registers) and If all your performance-relevant code is using SSE you might not suffer from that limit. (I am not sure if there is a difference in avaiable registers for 64bit and 32bit SSE).